# How To Replace Exact Match words in Shell Script?

Tags: shell, sed, sh

I just wanted to replace Some Predefined Strings in shell Script:

string is like this:

```
 #! /bin/bash
 CONTENT="DEAR [NAME]"
```

I wanted to replace [NAME] with John.
I used below code:

```
#! /bin/bash
CONTENT="DEAR [NAME]"
echo "$CONTENT" | sed -r 's/[[NAME]]+/John/g'
```

Got the below result ;
    DEAR [NAMJhon

i need result like this "DEAR Jhon".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape the `[]`s:

```
$ echo $CONTENT | sed 's/\[NAME\]/John/'
DEAR John
```

but for this case you could go bash only:

```
$ echo ${CONTENT/\[NAME\]/John}
DEAR John
```

Comment: I need one more help ; suppose [NAME]  is two times in String and i wanted to replace both , in that case above Code only replacing the first occurance of [NAME].

Comment: For `sed` add `g` to the end: `sed 's/\[NAME\]/John/g'`. I need to check for bash.

Comment: For the bash it's: `echo ${CONTENT//\[NAME\]/John}` (two `//`s to start with). ([This](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) for the reference)

Comment: Thanks James Brown .

Answer (score 1):

Use escape sequence.

```
#! /bin/bash
CONTENT="DEAR [NAME]"
echo "$CONTENT" | sed 's/\[NAME\]/John/g'
```

Gives output as

DEAR John